# Get DefaultAppPool AppData folder from the web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, iis-7

I have a web application which is running from `DefaultAppPool` account. I want to write some files into the DefaultAppPool's AppData folder (or any other folder, which is 100% accessible from the account my application is running)

I've tried

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)
```

but for some reason, it returns an empty string.

```
Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile)
```

returns `C:\\Users\DefaultAppPool` as expected.

How can I get the AppData path for DefaultAppPool?

**EDIT:**
This code is executed in the Model

Comment: Have you tried getting the environment variable value %AppData%?

Comment: Yes, I've tried   `System.Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariables("%AppData%")`, but it returns "C:\\Windows\\system32\\config\\systemprofile\\AppData\\Roaming" and my web app can't write there

Comment: Even though there is a user directory for DefaultAppPool on disk, the profile for the 'user' is not loaded when running the AppPool, that's why `Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)` is empty and that's why you get the systemprofile instead. hutchonoid's solution seem to work but I would actually advise against storing any permanent data in the user directory of the AppPool identity user. What if some admin decides to change the identity of the AppPool? For temporary data you can always reply on %temp%

Comment: @PeterHahndorf +1, I'm trying to find the place where I can store the state of my web app's trial. Temp is obviously not good so I thought about web app user's appdata folder and registry. Maybe you have a better idea for me? thanks

Comment: I always have a parent directory for any app, under it is the document root itself (for the physical path in IIS), but I have additional directories for logs, downloads or data that should be accessible by my app but now directly browse-able. You just need to make sure that the AppPool user account have sufficient NTFS permissions. If you can't change you directory structure, you could use APP_Data or create another folder under the document root and make it non-accessible for browsers (you could use Hidden Segments in Request Filtering in IIS).

Comment: @PeterHahndorf the problem is that if someone uninstals my application and deletes the installation folder, the trial information will be wiped too. That's why I thought about the web app's user directory as it doesn't matter under which account the app is executed, it will always have a permission to write there.

Comment: @VladL - I understand, you are trying to write some trial/licencing information somewhere, ideally somewhere, where your customer can not change it, right? That's a whole different question, but I don't think the user directory is a good place for it.

Comment: @PeterHahndorf right, but why not? It's not the logged in user's directory but of the web app's user, which is typically DefaultAppPool

Comment: @PeterHahndorf ideally I would love to have more than one place on the HDD to store this kind of the information.

Comment: @Vladl - Because the user can easily change the AppPool your web-app runs in, and delete the old AppPool, then all your data is lost. There is no DefaultAppPool on any of my servers. You should ask a new question about a good location for the data you are trying to store. This gets off topic

Comment: @PeterHahndorf the user can delete anything, if he knows where to look and what to delete :) Please see my new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20641230/best-place-to-store-the-trial-data-for-the-web-application

Answer (score 1):

I do it like this:

```
var path = string.Format("{0}\\{1}", Environment.GetFolderPath(System.Environment.SpecialFolder.UserProfile), "AppData")
```

Comment: +1 it works but looks a little bit like a hardcoded string for me

Comment: Totally agree, +1 question. I could only get the ApplicationData folder to return for me, I gave up on it but i'm interested to see if anyone has the full answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I did it like this:

```
string apPath = Path.Combine(System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.ApplicationPhysicalPath, "App_Data");
```

Comment: Late to the party, but OP wants to access the Application Data folder for the IIS AppPool user, not the App_Data folder in the web root.