# Best place to store the trial data for the web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, permissions, trial

After reading a lot of SO topics about how to design a trial for the desktop software I still have some questions about trial for Web Application.

I have a ASP.Net MVC Web Application and I'm offering a time limited trial for that.
The applicaion will run in IIS > 7.0 so it has a very limited acces to the system and that is why there are not a lot of places for storing the information about the remaining trial.

I'm not trying to make my software "uncrackable", but it shouldn't be obvious for an average user how to reset the trial so I want to store the trial data at least at **two** places.

Until now I have found two places where to store the info:

1) In registry under `CurrentUser`. The User, under which account my web app is running will always have the writing permission to this key.

2) WebApp user's AppData folder. It should be accessible as well, but I couldn't find the safe way to determine the path to this folder (see [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20637013/get-defaultapppool-appdata-folder-from-the-web-application))

**Question:** what are the good or best place(s) to store the trial information for the web application?

Thank you

Comment: Is there a compelling reason you don't use the database?

Comment: How does the "trial" become a "active" version? Does the presence of something make it a trial? If so, I'd recommend changing that to absence of something makes it a trial. So assume everything is a "trial" unless an "unlock key" or something is present.

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud my app will use the database, but reinstalling the app and dropping the database will also wipe the trial info and this is something that I'm trying to avoid

Comment: @VladL, I believe to answer this question the community is going to need *a lot more information* about how a customer *gets a trial.* In other words, if they get their own database, how? Do they get their own sub-domain that is thus deployed to IIS? In short, we don't have enough information to really understand your architecture.

Comment: @ChrisHaas through the different license keys which are validated offline, but I like your idea, thank you!

Comment: @MichaelPerrenoud I do not ask the comunity about the whole trial concept. I just need some places on the system there a limited user can store the encrypted installation date and something else. But I've never deployed the web apps (it's not my job) so maybe I'm missing some important info.

Comment: I agree with Michael: The more info you provide the better.  I don't normally like to get too far into peoples business but I'm questioning why this is even a web app.  Sounds like an average user is supposed to install your "web app" onto their local machine.. and then access it from that same machine?  That sounds very very odd; the vast majority of Win 7 desktops don't have IIS installed... Either way, you want the absence of a valid key to indicate that it's trial software. Further, I don't know why your installer would drop the database on a reinstall.  That's very odd too.

Comment: @ChrisLively it's a server web application so it's installed on the server and many users will access it from the intranet. Not the installer will drop the database, but it can be dropped manually and then simple reinstall will start the trial from the beginning.

Comment: I really don't understand why you people questioning such things like why it is a web app? It was designed and implemented as a web app because the company decided to create and to sell a web app. I'm a part of the developer team and have to implement a trial functionality. I've described what I'm trying to achieve, what I've found and what my problems are and my one line question is pretty clear even without the whole description. Could you please assume that I have some clue and know what I'm doing? The only thing I'm asking for is a better place to save the installation date.

Comment: Why not just provide a trial license key that has the expiration date baked into it when they sign up?  You seem to already have key checking and generation, take it one step further and supply a trial key.  When checking the key, pull out the expiration date.  This does not prevent resetting the system clock, but that's an entirely different ball of wax.  When they choose to upgrade, they update the key in the config file.  If they dont, then your software will not work with the expired trial key even if they uninstall/reinstall.

Comment: @Tommy thanks for your idea. The system clock reset is a problem that I want to prevent too. I'm saving the last access date on every access somewhere and compare the current date with the saved one. If the day is different, the new date is saved and I add the difference as an int (counter used days) at some other place. So if the clock is reseted, the difference is negative, but I'm adding it as Math.Abs() anyway to the counter. The company decided to have one trial key for everyone and this is how it works with other our products, so I can't really change it now.

Answer (score 1):

I did some reviews and there are a few articles that have some information regarding creating trial software versions:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/473278/Creating-Secure-Trial-Versions-for-NET-Application

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/398130/Software-Copy-Protection-for-Net-Applications-a-Tu

These both target actual Windows Forms apps, but the concepts and thoughts on things like system clock manipulation could help spur some ideas for you and your dev team.  Basically, there is no bullet-proof way to prevent someone from attempting to outsmart your protection.  Like you said, you are not trying to make this hacker-proof, just keep people honest.

Whatever route you go, you and your company need to ask yourself where you stand to lose more income 1) people stealing your app or 2) trials failing because of over-zealous DRM.  I suspect in the majority of cases (unless you are a game maker), #2 is the bigger concern.